# Error: connection refused: localtunnel.me:undefined (check your firewall settings)

Tags: xampp, localtunnel

I'm trying to set up localtunnel on Ubuntu, but I keep getting the error :

```
your url is: undefined
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/bin/client:58
        throw err;
        ^

Error: connection refused: localtunnel.me:undefined (check your firewall settings)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/lib/TunnelCluster.js:47:32)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1256:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

I am using Xampp. What could be the issue?

Thank you all.

Comment: What's the command you're running and options that you're passing?

Comment: As a matter of seeing if something else works, try https://telebit.cloud Since you're on Windows you'd have to use `npm install -g telebit` and then `./telebit http 3000` (or whatever port xampp is running on). The instructions on the website for Mac and Linux. If that doesn't work either then you know it's most likely a network issue specific to your setup.

Comment: try `lt --port 3000 --s somename --o` and port to be your port, in example is 3000, because my is 3000, and try this 2-3 times. Error must gone it works for me

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu :

`sudo ufw disable`

Use the above command to disable the firewall 
and create your local tunnel using:

`lt --port 8000`

Comment: Disabling the firewall is not really a good solution

Comment: It dosn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with `sudo`. I had the same issue while executing as the normal user but running it with `sudo` helped out. You can also try running it as `www-data`

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. Try improve on the existing answer or provide the different perspective instead of reiterate the same concept. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this whole [issue](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/258) I can conclude It is not your pc's fault, but the localtunnel server is under heavy load. You should try again in some time.